# community cloud record detail page (detail and related ) only showing half page only

Tags: community, lightning-community

community cloud record detail page (detail  and related ) only showing half page only.but i need full page displayed it is possible or not please check below images 
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This half page layout is because the page by default has the 'Record Information Tabs' component in it.

[image]

Click the trashcan in the blue area on the top right hand corner of the Record Information tabs then open the Components scroll down to Records and then drag the 'Record Detail' component over into the space that the Record Information Tabs component was in before and now the record details fill the whole space as in the next two images. Then you can add back the related lists by pulling in the Related List component - this has two settings Narrow or Wide which controls how the record list are displayed on the page.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If this resolves your problem please select the tick next to the answer to accept it and mark the question as answered.

Comment: Hi Dave, i have tried your approach but still related list of opportunity is not showing as full page. Can you please help me on this.

Comment: Is that the list that shows not as a full page or the Opportunity detail?

Comment: Hi Dave, Opportunity detail page is showing fully but not realted lists of Opportunity. How to show the related list information full page. Please help me on this.

Comment: Have a look at the updated reply with the related lists component.

Comment: Currently Related list showing fully but Record Information tab also showing related lists with half page. Whenever i click related list tab on "Record Information Tab" then related lists show as fully.

Comment: In Addition to @Dave Humm great answer, you can gather the separated components of "Record Related List" and "Record Detail" into "Tabs" Content component